# A proposition about positive random variables and expected values

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have problems to give a proof for the following proposition:

> Consider a random variable $X$ with values in $[0,+\infty]$. If $P(X=+\infty)>0$, then $E(X)=+\infty$ (notation: $E(X)=\int X \,dP$).

Do you have any idea?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define random variable $Y$ by $\omega\mapsto 0$ if $X(\omega)<\infty$ and $\omega\mapsto +\infty$ otherwise.

Then $0\leq Y\leq X$ hence $0\leq \mathbb E(Y)\leq\mathbb E(X)$.

$Y$ only take the values in $\{0,+\infty\}$ and  $P(Y=+\infty)=P(X=+\infty)>0$.

This leads directly to $\mathbb E(Y)=(+\infty)\times P(Y=+\infty)=+\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ is positive, $E(X) \geq +\infty P(X = +\infty) = +\infty$.

Otherwise, you can use [the definition of $\int XdP$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration), it is defined as the sup of integration of simple functions that approaches $X$ from below. Remark integration of these simple functions on $\{X = +\infty\}$ tends to $+\infty$